# How to update a json file in azure web job?

Tags: json, azure, azure-webjobs

I created an Azure web job under my website to run an application every week.

My application loads from a json file its last running time in order to select data modified after its last execution. If the application completes its job successfully it updates the value on the json file. In order to update the file i'm using the bellow code:

```
 public static void SaveConfig(Config cnf)
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/config.json";
        File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cnf, Formatting.Indented));
    }
```

The problem is that on the Azure web job it runs perfect with no errors but it doesn't update my json file as expected. I have to notice here that the config.json is deployed to Azure as part of the web job, and i can find it through ftp or App service editor under path App_Data/jobs/triggered/MyApp

Comment: Two things: to find your file you can access the webapp using project kudu {yourwebsitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net and check the files. Also,you can only wirte to the root of the WebApp so that might be why your file is not saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebJobs get shadow copied to a temp location before running, so if you try to modify a file that's part of what you deploy, you're only modifying the temp file. Generally, writing a WebJob that modifies its own file is not recommended. If your goal is to have a persistent data file, try saving it under %WEBJOBS_DATA_PATH%, which will be persisted.